# What if success_url is irrelevant with the model itself in Django

Tags: django

If the success_url is determined by the model, we can customize the generic view as below.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return '/object/%s' % (self.object.id)
```

But if the success_url is irrelevant with the model, such as, we want to return to the page before we entered the form page. It can be a detail page, a list page, or anything else. Can I store the referral url in the form? Any idea is appreciated.

~Hanson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the success page will not always be the same as otherwise you could just include the url with something like `reverse()` in `get_success_url`. 
For a dynamic redirect you could either, like you suggested add the url in a hidden input to the form or in the querystring of the url the form is posted to (eg. `/myurl?next=/redirect-url/`). Then you could do in your view class something like:

```
# url is in the form in a hidden input 'next'
def get_success_url(self):
    return request.POST['next']

# url is in the query string ?next=xxxx
def get_success_url(self):
    return request.GET['next']
```